# update pci.ids file to check for CUDA compatibility

Tags: 12.04, nvidia

I'm going through CUDA's documentation and following this page ([CUDA toolkit documentation](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-getting-started-guide-for-linux/index.html)) to see whether or not my machine and distro can support it.
To verify if i have a CUDA capable GPU, i had to enter this command

> lspci | grep -i nvidia

upon entering this command i got no result, and i followed it up by entering this

> update-pciids

^^i got the following result upon entering the aforementioned command

> update-pciids: /usr/share/misc/pci.ids.new is read-only

any ideas on how to verify the compatibility of my card with CUDA?

Answer (score 3):

Sorry late, but I just found this when I was struggling myself. Must be super user for that,

```
sudo update-pciids
```

Comment: Thank you for answering, the `update-pciids` command works now, but despite that, `lspci | grep -i nvidia` shows no result. any idea why?

Comment: I really don't. Appologies.

Comment: Same here, it's blank after updating. My guess is that it mean this system doesn't support CUDA...?

Answer (score 0):

If you know you have Nvidia hardware, and it does not show up in the various OS listing, check that your UEFI Settings/BIOS does not have the "discrete" video hardware disabled.  That would make the hardware invisible to the OS.