# Ubuntu 14.04 update-pci ids /usr/share/misc/pci.ids.new is read-only

Tags: 14.04, cuda

I try to install cuda 7.5 on Ubuntu 14.04. To verify that your GPU is CUDA-capable, I write

```
$ lspci | grep -i nvidia
```

command. I don't see anything. Then i write

```
update-pciids
```

I take

```
update-pci ids /usr/share/misc/pci.ids.new is read-only
```

message. I login as a root but i can not do. Are there anyone who solved this problem? I also new in ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

From [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/334945/601621)

```
sudo update-pciids
```

Verified working on my Ubuntu 16.04 machine.