# lspci | grep -i nvidia command not working -- To check for cuda compatability

Tags: 14.04, nvidia, cuda

I'm trying to follow step 2.1 from this guide:

http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/#axzz4WNL7OgLr

I tried `sudo update-pciids` as suggested in this thread

[update pci.ids file to check for CUDA compatibility](https://askubuntu.com/questions/299402/update-pci-ids-file-to-check-for-cuda-compatibility)

and the response I get is:

`Downloaded daily snapshot dated 2017-10-12 03:15:01`

However, when I try `lspci | grep -i nvidia` aftewards I still get no response.

I'm using ubuntu 16.04.

Thank you.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `lspci | grep -i nvidia` produces an empty output you don't have a Nvidia GPU connected to your system (or it's broken) which means you can't use CUDA on that system.

Comment: Thanks. It seems since I'm using ubuntu on a  virtual machine, it's not automatically connected.

Comment: @Moondra Like I commented on your other question, you can't use CUDA inside the guest system of a virtual machine unless the virtualisation driver is capable of and configured for host GPU pass-through. Afaik VMware isn't.